# Problem with jQuery's :nth-child and hidden rows

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table with a zebra-effect:

```
$('table.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('darker');
```

Now I have to hide/show certain rows though. But when I do this, those hidden rows will still count and the zebra-effect doesn't really work anymore. Say rows 1 is shown, 2 is hidden, and 3 is shown again. Now both 1 and 3 are displayed on top of each other since 2 is hidden, but they both have the darker background from the `darker` class since they're both odd.

I tried something like this:

```
$('table.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(odd):not(.hide)').addClass('darker');
```

But it seems like it doesn't skip the rows with the class `hide` when counting, causing the same problem.

Is there a trick to only count the rows that are not hidden and determine whether *they* are odd or even? Preferably using the jQuery selectors instead of some function.

Comment: instead of :not(.hide) try :visible http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$('table.zebra tbody tr:not(.hide)').filter(":odd").addClass('darker');
```